# Create a foreign table with only specific columns

Tags: postgresql

I would like to know if there is a way to create a foreign table only with specific columns and conditions in PostgreSQL. For example i saw someone suggest this command but it doesn't really work because the OPTIONS `(table '')` at the bottom doesn't actually exist.

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE app_users (
id INT NOT NULL,
login VARCHAR(190),
email VARCHAR(190),
"name" VARCHAR(255)
) SERVER fdw_app
OPTIONS (
table '(SELECT id, login, email, "name" FROM public."user" WHERE login like ''app-%'')');
```

Sql returns that the available options are only `schema_name, table_name, use_remote_estimate, updatable, fetch_size`

Is there an actual way to do this or is it impossible?

Comment: Please specify which foreign data wrapper is being used. Available OPTIONS are determined by the foreign data wrapper.